# How to get value name of a python protobuf message's enum field

Tags: python, enums, protocol-buffers

I'm not into protobuf yet, but i'll try to phrase a question. Given i have:

```
  enum SourceType {
     WEB = 1;
  }
  message Message {
    optional SourceType source = 6;
  }
```

I have message which is an instance of Message and I want to get the value of the source just like printing the message. But doing message.source gives me the code. I want to get the value just from the object, not by using other enums/mappings/constants. In the last line I have an example of how I can reach the expected value, but i'm looking for a more elegant way.

```
  > message    
  <Message_pb2.Message object at 0x7f78561a83c8>
  > print message
  source: WEB
  > print message.source 
  1
  > message.DESCRIPTOR.fields_by_name['source'].enum_type.values_by_number[1].name 
  WEB
```

Answer (score 6):

The `EnumTypeWrapper` class has a `Name` method, which returns the name of an `enmum` value. So in this case, after importing the `SourceType` from `Message_pb2`, `SourceType.Name()` will return the name for the value.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that using the `EnumDescriptor` as you did in your example is the only way to get an enum value's name. You could, of course, write a helper function around it to make it less verbose.

Comment: i did write a helper function :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EnumTypeWrapper.Name()` method

In case there are several items in a enum, `EnumTypeWrapper.Name()` requires positional argument 'number', e.g.

```
 enum SourceType {
     DB = 0;
     WEB = 1;
 }
```

`SourceType.Name(1)` will return `WEB`